# Como calcular moeda aparecendo casas decimais em JS?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um cálculo dinâmico para fazer, sem precisar clicar em botões. Até consegui, mas a parte que não sei é fazer aparecer como casas decimais, já que estamos falando de moeda.

```js
function multiplica()
{
numer1 = parseInt(document.frmitementrada.quantidade.value);
numer2 = parseInt(document.frmitementrada.preuni.value);

soma = numer1 + numer2;

document.frmitementrada.total.value = soma;
}
```

```html
<form name="frmitementrada" id="frmitementrada">
<td width="20%">

<INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="3" NAME="quantidade" value="0">
<INPUT TYPE="text" onkeyup="multiplica()" SIZE="3" NAME="preuni"  value="0" >

<INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="3" NAME="total">
</td>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao invés de `parseInt()`, use `parseFloat()`.

O [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) transforma em números inteiros, ou seja, sem casas decimais. Já o [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parsefloat) transforma em um número operável qualquer.

```js
function multiplica()
{
numer1 = parseFloat(document.frmitementrada.quantidade.value);
numer2 = parseFloat(document.frmitementrada.preuni.value);

soma = numer1 + numer2;

document.frmitementrada.total.value = soma;
}
```

```html
<form name="frmitementrada" id="frmitementrada">
<td width="20%">

<INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="3" NAME="quantidade" value="0" />
<INPUT TYPE="text" onkeyup="multiplica()" SIZE="3" NAME="preuni"  value="0" />

<INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="3" NAME="total" />
</td>
</form>
```

Mas lembre-se que terá de usar ponto `.`, ao invés de vírgula `,`, nas casas decimais.

Caso queira limitar as casa decimais, pode usar o [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), ou o [`.toPrecision()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision).

O `toFixed`, limita o número de casas depois da vírgula, já o `toPrecision` limita o número de casa ao todo. No seu caso, usando o `toFixed`:

```js
function multiplica()
{
numer1 = parseFloat(document.frmitementrada.quantidade.value);
numer2 = parseFloat(document.frmitementrada.preuni.value);

soma = numer1 + numer2;

document.frmitementrada.total.value = (soma.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<form name="frmitementrada" id="frmitementrada">
<td width="20%">

<INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="3" NAME="quantidade" value="0" />
<INPUT TYPE="text" onkeyup="multiplica()" SIZE="3" NAME="preuni"  value="0" />

<INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="3" NAME="total" />
</td>
</form>
```

Comment: Teria como eu enviar para total com duas casas decimais a direita? e no máximo 3 a esquerda?

Comment: @gezer Teria sim, vou editar a resposta com sua dúvida...

Comment: beleza estarei aguardando.

Comment: @gezer, olhe a edição. Caso tenha em mente, algo mais complexo, como uma mascara, é melhor olhar outra respoosta aqui do SOpt, tem várias sobre isso. Ou fazer uma nova pergunta. Já que esta era apenas sobre isso mesmo.

Comment: show obrigado isso mesmo agora parto para mascara eu tenho um esquema aqui vou adaptar. precisava entender melhor como funcionava obrigado.

Comment: @gezer, de nada :)

Comment: merecia até um bonus! Parabéns!