# Pegar os valores de dois inputs, realizar o cálculo e exibir em um terceiro input

Tags: jquery, html

Galera, estou desenvolvimento um formulário que irá calcular o valor do frete e descontar os débitos para chegar ao valor líquido que o Motorista tem para receber. Porém eu queria que alguns campos exibissem os valores conforme o usuário vai preenchendo o formulário.

Por exemplo a imagem, o campo "Diferença de Peso" irá calcular o "Peso de Saída" - "Peso de Chegada" para saber a diferença. 
Alguém sabe de algum tutorial de JavaScript/jQuery que realize algo parecido que eu consiga me basear?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var tPesoSaida   = document.getElementById( 'ps' );
            var tPesoChegada = document.getElementById( 'pc' );
            var tPesoTotal   = document.getElementById( 'pt' );

            tPesoSaida.onkeyup=calcula;
            tPesoChegada.onkeyup=calcula;

            function calcula() {
                tPesoTotal.value = (tPesoSaida.value - tPesoChegada.value);
            }
        </script>
        <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">
            <label>Peso de Saída</label>
            <input type="text" value="0" placeholder="37000" name="PesoSaida" id="ps"/>
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">
            <label>Peso de Chegada</label>
            <input type="text" value="0" placeholder="37090" name="PesoChegada" id="pc"/>
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">
            <label>Diferença de Peso</label>
            <input type="text" value="0" name="PesoTotal"  id="pt" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: E o que você tentou fazer até agora? Qual a sua dificuldade específica?

Comment: Eu andei pesquisando, porém não consegui encontrar nada relacionado a jQuery que seja como se fosse um "sair do campo" pra realizar o evento.

Comment: Com isso vc pode calcular enquanto o usuário vai digitando... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed

Comment: Mas como vou falar quem é o input1, input2 e input3? Para passar os valores.

Comment: Id, name do campo... qualquer seletor válido.

Comment: Está muito errado da forma que coloquei na pergunta agora? @gmsantos

Comment: @JulianoBazzi se puser o trecho do HTML que tem os campos, ajuda.

Comment: @Bacco editei a pergunta com o código fonte do formulário. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue uma demonstração bem simples de como fazer em JS:

```js
var tQtd = document.getElementById( 'qtd' );
var tVlr = document.getElementById( 'vlr' );
var tTot = document.getElementById( 'tot' );

tVlr.onkeyup=calcula;
tQtd.onkeyup=calcula;

function calcula() {
  tTot.value = tQtd.value * tVlr.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="qtd" value="0" name="quantidade"><br>
<input id="vlr" value="0" name="valor"><br>
<input id="tot" value="0" name="total" readonly>
```

Notar que não está sendo feita nenhuma verificação dos valores, apenas coloquei o básico para demonstrar como fazer.

Se precisar de coisas mais avançadas, como controlar o separador de decimais, e ajustar a formatação numérica, temos respostas explicando como fazer aqui mesmo:

> [Como calcular moeda aparecendo casas decimais em JS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109617/70)

Comment: Utilizar um Framework CSS pode influenciar no funcionamento do JavaScript? Editei a pergunta com o trecho do código que fiz baseado no seu.

Comment: Se quer mesmo usar name, precisa de um índice: `var tPesoSaida = document.getElementsByName( 'PesoSaida' )[0];` mas ainda recomendo o ID.

Comment: O OnKeyUp no caso quando o usuário der uma tab que ele vai efetuar?

Comment: @JulianoBazzi quando digitar qualquer coisa e soltar a tecla. Tem que ser no Up, pois no Down o valor do campo ainda não é alterado. Se preferir que mude somente quando o campo perder o foco, é `onchange`. Se rodar o demo acima, vai ver que muda quando vc está digitando.

Comment: Se quiser cobrir situações mais complexas (copiar e colar, mudanças por JS, etc) melhor um timer atualizando o campo. Em vez de chamar a função no key, chama no setinterval.

Comment: Eu sou novo nessa área de JavaScript, estou começando a mexer agora com ele.. Eu não tenho que dar um "set" pro código passar o resultado pro input do total?

Comment: @JulianoBazzi você clicou no "executar trecho de código" acima e testou? A função `calcula()` faz exatamente isso: calcula e coloca no input.

Comment: fiz o teste e realmente funciona, só no meu código que não

Comment: `tTot` é o campo que tem o total. Estamos colocando o resultado na propriedade `value` deste campo (ou seja, mudando efetivamente o valor). Precisa conferir se não tem coisa digitada errada. Notou o índice que eu mencionei no comentário sobre pegar por nome?

Comment: Sim, eu arrumei o id e no código também isso. Mas continua sem alterações no campo do total.

Comment: a forma de colocar o código está correta? É antes dos campos mesmo?

Comment: O ideal pra quase qualquer JS é carregar no OnLoad, depois da página já toda montada. Se não for fazer no OnLoad, pode deixar esse JS no final do body, depois de todos os outros elementos.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.